# Should the type of an argument for a non-type template parameter match the type of the parameter?

Tags: c++, hash, language-lawyer, specialization, non-type-template-parameter

I was instantiating a `std::unordered_set` of `std::array<int,3>`, I found that the following code cannot pass compilation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>

namespace std {
    template <class T>
    inline void hash_combine(size_t& seed, const T& v) {
        hash<T> hasher;
        seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }

    template <typename T, int N>
    struct hash<array<T, N>>
    {
        size_t operator()(array<T, N> arr) const noexcept {
            size_t hs = 0;
            for (auto iter = arr.begin(); iter != arr.end(); iter++) {
                hash_combine(hs, *iter);
            }
            return hs;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::unordered_set<std::array<int, 3>> arrset;
    std::cout << arrset.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message tells me that the specialization `hash<array<T, N>>` is not detected. After some hard work, I found that it is caused by the mismatching between the type of non-type template argument `N` and the type of parameter (`size_t`). But shouldn't the compiler cast the `int N` to `size_t N` automatically? Since the usage of `std::array<int, true>` also passes the compilation, as I have tested on g++9.4. Is there any specific mention in the C++ standard regarding this particular situation?

Comment: You should use the correct type (or at least `auto`), but other compilers don't complain: https://godbolt.org/z/Ybf35PzzY

Comment: Did you try a different platform/compiler version?!

Comment: @Red.Wave It appears to fail on gcc but compiles successfully on msvc and clang, as tested by Bob__.

Comment: Is gcc up to date?! What version are you using? On a modern vesion, that should be a defect.

Comment: @Red.Wave Yes, gcc 13 fails to compile it. https://godbolt.org/z/Ybf35PzzY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::hash` is a red herring, as do I interpret the formal UB described in @Jason's answer to be, w.r.t. to OP's question:

> But shouldn't the compiler cast the `int N` to `size_t N` automatically?

A minimal example:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
struct A {};

template<typename T>
struct S { S() = delete; };

template<int N>
struct S<A<N>> {};  // #1

S<A<4>> s{};  // error ("use of deleted function")
              // picks non-defined primary template
```

[[temp.class.spec.match]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.class.spec.match) describes the relevant rules [**emphasis** mine]:

> **/1** When a class template is used in a context that requires an instantiation of the class, it is necessary **to determine whether the
> instantiation is to be generated using the primary template or one of
> the partial specializations**. [...]
>
> **/2** A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list **if the template arguments of the partial
> specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument
> list**, [...]

The actual template argument list, from `#1` above, is `A<4>`, from which we can deduce the type `A<std::size_t{4}>`. The template argument list for the partial specialization, however, is `A<int{N}>`, which is not a match for the actual template argument list. In fact, the partial specialization #1 will never be used (given the current example), as we cannot produce a template argument list that will match it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the hash function to the template arguments too. Here is a revised version of your code (with some small feedback as well).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <array>

namespace std
{
    namespace details
    {
        template <class type_t>
        inline void hash_combine(size_t& seed, const type_t& v)
        {
            auto hash = std::hash<type_t>()(v);
            seed ^= hash + 0x9e3779b9ul + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2); // initialize magic number as std::size_t too 
        }
    }

    template <typename type_t, std::size_t N>
    struct hash<std::array<type_t, N>>
    {
        size_t operator()(const std::array<type_t, N>& arr) const noexcept // pass by const ref to avoid copies
        {
            size_t hs{ 0ul };

            for (const auto& value : arr) // use range based for loop
            {
                details::hash_combine(hs, value);
            }
            return hs;
        }
    };

}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::array<int,3>> arrset;

    arrset.insert({ 1,2 });
    std::cout << arrset.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is specifically about specialization of `std::hash`. Providing a separate costume hash is not the answer.

Comment: Now you haven't answered the question. Why should `N` be `size_t`?

Comment: Look at template argument for [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Using size_t will ensure you have more capacity then int, and std::size_t cannot have a negative value (which doesn't make sense for containser), its what all the containers use too.

Comment: I know what `std::array` is. The question was about the reason for partial specialization failure. And you didn't provide anything close to an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, but indeed I have not answered your question. Nor can I at the moment. Either your or my solution should work AFAIK, and indeed I failed to check gcc compiler (and only used my msvc one)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think the program(OP's) has undefined behavior as explained in my answer.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Simplest would be to use a lambda perhaps.

Comment: Yes it would (and it is what I would use), but OP asked for overload in std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Specializing `std::hash` for `std::array<int, N>` leads to **undefined behavior**.

From [namespace.std]:

> **Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace std provided that**
>
> (a) **the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined
> type** and
>
> (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

(emphasis mine)

But the first requirement of having at least one program-defined type is not satisfied in your example. From [defns.prog.def.type]:

> non-closure **class type or enumeration type that is not part of the C++ standard library and not defined by the implementation**, or a closure type of a non-implementation-provided lambda expression, or an instantiation of a program-defined specialization.

---

One possible solution is to use a lambda.